# Pre-populate admin created order in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I have an external website with a list of addresses. I would like to add a link to that page that when clicked, takes me to the Add New Order form in Woocommerce admin, and have the billing and shipping addresses pre-populated, from like GET variables or something. The billing and shipping addresses would be the same.

Is there a way to accomplish this?